# Get values from NSTextField, NSComboBox in a unified way?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have the following method set as the action of an `NSComboBox` and two `NSTextField`s:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == comboBox) {
        [myModel setFoo1:[comboBox intValue]];
    } else if (sender == intTextField) {
        [myModel setFoo2:[intTextField intValue]];
    } else if (sender == floatTextField) {
        [myModel setFoo3:[floatTextField floatValue]];
    }
}
```

I wondered if I could make that method into something like this, in order to increase maintainability:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    [myModel setValue:[sender value] forKey:[sender identifier]];
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work like that. I get the following error:

```
[NSComboBox value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed42029430
```

How do I get the values from the controls in a uniform way (i.e. as an object), no matter if `int` or `float`? The KVC `setValue:forKey:` method I use on my model should be able to deduce the actual type of the value object (i.e. the kind of `NSNumber` in this case) just fine, right?

Or is this not possible at all? (I know I could probably use bindings to bind the UI controls to the model's value fields, but that's not what I want to do.)

Comment: Did you try using `-(id)objectValue`?

Comment: No, I didn't. That appears to do the trick. Thanks a lot! Would you mind making your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I went ahead and made it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `NSTextField` and `NSComboBox` are subclasses of `NSControl`, you should be able to use `-(id)objectValue` to get the control's value (or selected value) in a uniform way.